# Is tethering/hotspot dangerous for your Android phone?

Tags: hardware, wifi-hotspot, tethering

Is using your Android phone as a portable hotspot/tethering dangerous for your hardware part?

In our dormitory we do not have good internet connection and I'm forced to use my phone as an internet spot 24/7 (we basically can't even search a thing on Google)

How dangerous this can be? I am not talking from a *security* point of view, but rather from an *hardware* point of view (short-circuit, not being able to use Wi-Fi in the future etc)

I am aware that keeping my phone connected 24/7 to my laptop will drain battery's life

Comment: The phone is designed to have this functionality, it should have zero effect on the hardware other than the fact that you know it could effect battery life... Why would you think it would be of any issue?

Comment: I am using it for hours daily, and because I do not know how exactly it is built, I'm afraid not to burn a piece inside or something like that

Comment: Some people use it all day, every day... You have nothing to worry about. The only possible issues are if you are charging it simultaneously and for some reason it gets too hot, but this isn't the fault of the hotspot it the design of the device if it occurs. You have nothing to worry about.

Comment: I agree with acejavelin, only the  battery may be degraded a little bit as a result of overheating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't enough/real evidence suggesting that tethering is harmful to device hardware. AFAICT this is a feature-by-design that any android device (supporting tethering) should be able to handle without detrimental effects other hardware except perhaps that the battery may be degraded a little bit due to overheating.

(*Just like using your PC to play high graphics games 24/7 with a gaming PC, even though the PC seems to be "overworking", you'd agree with me that's what its designed for. Isn't it?*)